# structure map 4 property injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I didn't get why setter property now work, I've configured container, but value if this property null

```
container.Configure(_ =>
{
    _.Policies.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IUserRepository>().Use<UserRepository>();

    _.For<IRequestRepository>().Use<RequestRepository>()
    .SetLifecycleTo(uniqueRequest);

    _.For<IRssRepository>().Use<RssRepository>();
    _.For<IUserRepository>().Use<UserRepository>();
});
```

And then in class which I want use this property:

```
[SetterProperty]
public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }
```

Maybe problem is that I've constructor in UserRepository?

```
private readonly IRequestRepository _repository;

public UserRepository(IRequestRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

Also question, in structure map documentation we injecting interface, why not class? I mean in constructor and with setter property we declaring interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution for my problem is to use .Setter:

```
_.For<IRssRepository>().Use<RssRepository>()
.Setter<IRequestRepository>().Is<RequestRepository>();
```